# mysql moving 2 columns to one reordening the data where not 0

Tags: mysql, sql, window-functions, unpivot, sql-view

Could this table be re-arranged into one table (using a view )

```
+----+------+--------+
| id | item1| item2  |
+----+------+--------+
|  1 |    A |  B     |
|  2 |    0 |  B     |
|  3 |    A |  0     |
|  4 |    0 |  0     |
+----+------+--------+
```

Moving the data to this arrangement:

```
+----+------+
| id |items |
+----+------+
|  1 |    A |
|  2 |    B |
|  3 |    B |
|  4 |    A |
+----+------+
```

Comment: How come you get A for id = 4, when both item1 and item2 columns are 0?

Comment: The B from id=1 should go in its own row,  0 ignored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that to unpivot the data, while ignoring `0` values.

Consider:

```
select 
    row_number() over(order by t.id, t.seq) id,
    t.item
from (
    select id, 1 seq, item1 item from mytable where item1 <> '0'
    union all select id, 2, item2 from mytable where item2 <> '0'
) t
order by t.id, t.seq
```

Comment: thanks, but  id, t.item at the end of the select gives unexpected tokens and alias already used, when I try to run this

Comment: @100IT: which version of MySQL are you running?

Comment: Mysql version 5.7.26

Comment: `row_number()` requires MySQL 8.0. I am unsure that you really want a new sequence id in the result. In earlier versions, I would just do: `select id, seq, item from (....) t order by id, seq`

Comment: I realise I'm pushing the edge of what is possible here, (& what is logic to do) hence the negative responses, I guess. I did solve this using javascript on the client side, just wanted to know what is possible. Thanks for your help!